# Rails 3.1.x - image_tag doesn't use the precompiled file in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my views I put :

```
<%= image_tag("coin.png") %>
```

My original image is put on :

```
app/assets/images/coin.png
```

But in production mode the html code generated by image_tag is :

```
<img alt="Coin" src="/assets/coin.png">
```

Instead of hitting precompiled assets :

```
coin-aba0e66819d64251cb3bb4bb29b26eb2.png
```

(and naturally I cant see the image).

I didn't forgot to precompile my assets.

and my environment/production.rb is :

```
  config.cache_classes = true                                                                                                                                                                                   
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true                                                                                                                                                               
  config.serve_static_assets = false                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  config.assets.compress = true                                                                                                                                                                                                
  config.assets.js_compressor  = :uglifier
  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Accel-Redirect"
```

Thanks you a lot

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found it !!!!!!!

Add to your production.rb :

```
config.assets.digest = true
```

Comment: You rock. I had a rc.5 install where this was working without the new option.

Comment: Thanks for this. In addition, to fix the same problem in sass files, I had to replace "<%= asset_path('foo.png') %>" with "image-url('foo.png')".

Comment: Thank you so much. This app had been upgraded from 2.x up to 4.x over time. Turns out it was loading the old non-hash assets `header.jpg` and ignoring the `header-asdlfk12l3k4.jpg` altogether. This option was what was missing.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the latest part of [this railscasts](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline) Rails 3.1 won't use `?hash` cache expiring anymore. It will use an hash in the filename itself for assets. Don't know if for images is the same (haven't played with 3.1 yet), but it could be your issue.

Comment: Yes exactly I was wrong, but it the same issue. Thanks anyway